# ruby - zeromq detects client timeout, but client hangs

Tags: ruby, zeromq, mq

I'm trying to write a simple zmq system to replace an http client/server. My client times out when the server is off/unavailable, but does not retry or stop. What am I missing?

zmq_client.rb (modified version of Han Holl's lazy pirate client from zeromq guide)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zmq'

context = ZMQ::Context.new
socket = context.socket(ZMQ::REQ)
socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5559')

retries = 2
timeout = 10

retries.times do |tries|
  message = "Hello #{tries}"
  raise("Send: #{message} failed") unless socket.send(message)
  puts "Sending string [#{message}]"

  if ZMQ.select( [socket], nil, nil, timeout)
    message = socket.recv
    puts "Received reply [#{message}]"
    break
  else
    puts "timeout"
  end

end
socket.close
```

zmq_broker.rb (modified version of Oleg Sidorov's code found on zeromq guide)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ffi-rzmq'

context = ZMQ::Context.new
frontend = context.socket(ZMQ::ROUTER)
frontend.bind('tcp://*:5559')
poller = ZMQ::Poller.new
poller.register(frontend, ZMQ::POLLIN)

loop do
  poller.poll(:blocking)
  poller.readables.each do |socket|
    if socket === frontend
      loop do
        socket.recv_string(message = '')
        more = socket.more_parts?
        puts "#{message}#{more}"
        socket.send_string(message, more ? ZMQ::SNDMORE : 0)
        break unless more
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get an error `Send: #{message} failed` as soon as you try to `send` again after the first timeout, because your 2nd `send` will happen directly after the 1st `send`, and the REQ socket enforces that each `send` must go after (successful, not timeout-ed) `recv`.

In the lazy pirate pattern, you may need to send several requests before getting a reply. Solution suggested in [the 0MQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#toc67) is to close and reopen the REQ socket after an error. Your client doesn't close/reopen the REQ socket.

You may find helpful [the "Lazy Pirate client in Ruby" example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/rb%3alpclient) from the Guide.